# Backup database ignoring collation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I state that I'm new to SQL Server.

With my company we are planning to migrate from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012 and I have this question.

The application which uses SQL Server 2008 was born as a one language application (Italian in this case) but later has been converted to a multi language application that requires UTF-8 encoded data.

So the DB server has been filled with custom "collation" clause on column, query and procedures to avoid data encoding errors.

Now we have configured a SQL Server 2012 instance with all the right collation since the start and I was wondering in how to migrate data between servers.

How can I tell the dbms to dump the data into UFT-8 and omit all those "collation" clauses?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You can't really do that - either you need to "clean up" your database (remove all those specific collations from the columns) before you back it up, or then you need to restore it and then do the cleanup.

Comment: What about open the bak files and manually remove the collations ? Are those file clears to read ?

Comment: I don't know of any software to open and manipulate a `.bak` file - you need to restore, then cleanup. The only other way would be to just create the scripts to create the database, clean out all `COLLATION` statements, create your new database (without any collations), and then copy over the data (e.g. through Export/Import or via `INSERT INTO ... SELECT .....` statements, table by table)